# HttpServletRequestWrapper not working as expected

Tags: java, servlets, httpwebrequest, servlet-filters

I need to log request body content. So I used filter and **HttpServletRequestWrapper** as below for this purpose. But when I invoke `request.getParameter` from my servlet I'm not getting anything. Appreciate any help

RequestWrapper Code

```
public class MultiReadHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MultiReadHttpServletRequest.class);

private ByteArrayOutputStream cachedBytes;

public MultiReadHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    super(request);
    cachedBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    int n;
    while (-1 != (n = request.getInputStream().read(buffer))) {
        cachedBytes.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    return new CachedServletInputStream();
}

private class CachedServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {
    private ByteArrayInputStream input;

    public CachedServletInputStream() {
        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cachedBytes.toByteArray());
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return input.read();
    }
}

String getRequestBody() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder inputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream()));
    try {
        do {
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (null != line) {
                inputBuffer.append(line.trim());
            }
        } while (line != null);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error("Unable to get request body from request: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Just log error
            log.warn("Unable to close BufferReader: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    return inputBuffer.toString().trim();
}
```

My filter code

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                     FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if ((servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) && (messageTracerApiClient != null)) {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        MultiReadHttpServletRequest bufferedRequest = new MultiReadHttpServletRequest(httpServletRequest);

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setHost(bufferedRequest.getLocalAddr());
        message.setPayload(bufferedRequest.getRequestBody());
        messageTracerApiClient.publishMessage(message);

        System.out.println("bufferedRequest param= " + bufferedRequest.getParameterMap().size());

        filterChain.doFilter(bufferedRequest, servletResponse);
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Please note `bufferedRequest.getParameterMap().size()` also print 0 even there are parameter.

Comment: where are you calling `request.getParameter` in your code?

Comment: I used in my servlet and getting null. Also bufferedRequest.getParameterMap().size() give zero. But I can get bufferedRequest.getRequestBody() always.